# I can't translate an object from js to php. I can't send the data to the POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to send an object to a php file using XMLHttpRequest.

```
function sendAjax(url, data){
  const request= new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST',url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
  request.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(request.readyState!==4 || request.status !==200){
      return;
    }
    const response= JSON.parse(request.response);
    console.log(response);
  }
  request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

sendAjax('./postWork/removePost.php',{id})
```

```php
  $id=(int) $_POST['id'];
  exit(json_encode($_POST));
```

At the output I get

`[]`

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of the PHP code building this "JSON" ..?

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is not JSON!!